# Computer will not reboot after REISUB-ing

Tags: boot

After REISUB-ing my computer, upon reboot it went straight to BIOS.

I did a little googling and found boot repair, however it refused to recommend any method of repair, instead only allowing me to take a BootInfo summary.

Here is what it spat out: https://paste2.org/MXYvDn1C

Any advice on what to do?

Comment: What happens if you use the boot menu in the BIOS and tell it to boot from the HDD?

Comment: I notice /dev/sda1 is vfat. Is that intentional ? I didn't realise Ubuntu could be installed on a win32 partition. Can it be installed to a win32 partition, or is this possibly part of the problem ?

Comment: When trying to boot from the HDD, it attempts a boot and then reports that no shell.efi can be found. Additionally, I do not believe I made /dev/sda1/ vfat intentionally, but if it was beforehand then it was working perfectly fine.

Comment: Your drive isn't detected. `sda` is a ~8GB pen drive, the one you're running the live session from (SanDisk_Cruzer_Switch). What happened that made you use the last resort? It may give clues about the underlining issue.

Comment: I FIXED IT!!!

Through the live system I mounted /dev/sda1, then re-installed grub through:
`apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi`
`update-grub`
Afterwards I rebooted the system and took me to the decryption screen from which point everything was easy.

Thank you everyone for you help!